# Insert button link in error message on login fail in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-6

I'm building a website in Laravel. I just wanted to achieve very small functionality but I'm stuck.

When Login fails, Laravel throw error "These credentials do not match our records". I wanted to override this with **"No record found. Try again or Register"**.  in this message, Register should be a link for my register page.

I wrote this line under lang->en>auth.php

```
'failed' => 'No record found. Try again or' .'<a href="/register"></a>',
```

But my button is not showing in message.

How should I modify my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `{!! !!}` instead of `{{ }}` to prevent escaping on blade :

```
'failed' => 'No record found. Try again or <a href="/register">Register</a> here.',
```

And change this line on login page :

```
@error('email')
   <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
      <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
   </span>
@enderror
```

To,

```
@error('email')
   <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
      <strong>{!! $message !!}</strong>
   </span>
@enderror
```

Comment: This is what I' m seeing on login fail. 

No record found. Try again or &lt;a href=&quot;/register&quot;&gt;Register&lt;/a&gt;

Comment: @Shaan after tested on my local machine I updated my answer